# How can I create a page that will look different to each user/is customizable by each user?

Tags: my-site

The reason I want it to be a page rather than using the MySite Site Collection is because I want each user to be able to customize their page with certain document libraries and for it to be accessible in the main site. Not sure if it's even possible, but thought I'd ask anyways. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create a page that will look different to each user/is customizable by each user?

You can't in any manner which would be manageable. This is a bad idea and not really something that suits for SharePoint's architecture.

To some limit it's possible to have content which shows up as user-specific. This would be possible with e.g. libraries and lists by having views configured to show items created by `[Me]`, but that's about that.

What is not possible, is that you can't let users to customize one and only one page with varying content, as all of the content would need to be stored in the page despite how it would show up for an individual. Even you managed to achieve a page which shows up as blank for each unless they modify it by content specific to them, the SharePoint's limitations would be faced quickly. A SharePoint page has a limit of maximum 50 web parts per page, so I'd imagine 25 users would overcome that in a moment, or fewer.

To more realistically do something as you'd require, each user should have their own pages, which would solve some above mentioned showstoppers. However, even with this implementation, you'd face a **seriously unmanageable** permission management challenge. So, in other words, don't.

So what's left is that your best shot to have individually manageable content would be to utilize the built-in my sites.